Deploying MATLAB pre-trained neural network code to C++
I need to use Matlab coder package in order to depoloy a Matlab function to C++.
My function trains a netrwork and then uses it to predict some new data.
I saw that the "train" Matlab function can't be deployed, so the network first needs to be saved as a "Mat" file after it is trained inside Matlab environment, and then it needs to be loaded (as a Mat file), and used to predict my data.
There are 2 problems:

The  Matlab coder doesn't like the "load" function, which tries to load the pre-trained network.
it doesn't know how to deal with a network of type patternnet, which I trained and used. but I really must use this one since it was very tough to configure it properly for my data.

In this case, how do I deploy a pre-trained Matlab neural network of type patternnet to C++ dll, and call the function from there?
Can exporting to ONNX format be a good solution?
Thanks,
Gal

I don't think that you can do it in a simple way by just deploying Matlab code to C++. More correct way would be professional albeit somewhat more difficult:

Convert your Matlab model to some intermediate representation, for example, to ONNX. Take a look here. Other options could be tensorflow or pytorch, but I have no idea how difficult to do such convertion.
Use a relevant runtime, e.g. onnxruntime, tflite or pytorch counterpart, in c++ to run inference

OR

Convert your matlab to tensorflow/pytorch model, then convert it to ONNX, then ONNX to tensorrt and use it's runtime for inference


Thanks for the answer.
Do you think the complication would be the same for deployment to C# ?

@GalV I have no idea, but I would expect even more hurdles with C#, since it's not really well supported in deep learning community, as far as I know
